# Golang io.Copy() does not copy the file in CentOS

Tags: linux, file, go, io, server

I'm new to Go.
The following code works perfectly in windows, but not on CentOS.
I receive a multipart file from the client. The file has the correct size and there are no errors in reading it.

I need to create specific directories for the uploading user and save the files in there.
Directories are created just fine, but the file is not written.
This whole code runs with no errors on any stage.
I'm using Go v1.5.1 and BeeGo framework.

Here's the code:

```
    file , header , err := this.GetFile( "logo" );

    defer func(){
        err := file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println( err.Error() )
        }
    }()


    size , seekErr := file.Seek( 0 , 2 )
    maxSize , _ := beego.AppConfig.Int64( "MaxSize" )

    if err != nil {

        response.Data = err.Error()
        response.Success = false

    } else if seekErr != nil {

        response.Data = seekErr.Error()
        response.Success = false

    } else if size > maxSize {

        response.Data = "File too large: " + string(size)
        response.Success = false

    } else {

        if _ , errDE := os.Stat( "static/media/business" ) ; os.IsNotExist( errDE ){
            os.Mkdir( "static/media/business" , os.ModeDir )
            os.Chmod( "static/media/business" , 0755 )
        }

        offset , err := file.Seek( 0 , 0 )

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println( "Error seeking: " + err.Error() )
        }

        path := "static/media/business/" + u.( models.User ).Business.BusinessPage

        if _ , errDE := os.Stat( path ) ; os.IsNotExist( errDE ){
            os.Mkdir( path , os.ModeDir )
            os.Chmod( path , 0755 )
        }

        name := files.GenerateFileName( header.Filename , 24 )

        out , err := os.Create( path + "/" + name )

        if err != nil {

            response.Data = err.Error()
            response.Success = false

        } else {

            defer func(){
                err := out.Close()
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println( err.Error() )
                }
            }()

            _ , err = io.Copy( out , file )
            os.Chmod( path + "/" + name , 0755 )
            ...
```

Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

It appears that I can `io.Copy` to any *.txt file in the mentioned path, but not to an image file. Is that a clue?

Comment: First you are ignoring errors returned, e.g. from `os.Mkdir` or `os.Chdir`. Second: while creating the you check for `IsNotExist` *only* and do not handle e.g. `IsPermission`. Probably your directories have the wrong permissions: You `Chmod` only if you create the directory; if it exists already you never Chmod so it might deny writes.

Comment: @Volker The dirs have the right permissions, I don't use `Chdir` and `Mkdir` returns no error.

Comment: Does `io.Copy()` returns any meaningful error?